# PHP "Uninclude" or remove from memory?

Tags: php, exception, memory, memory-leaks, phpunit

I am building a testing tool to execute on directories of legacy PHP code that is *extremely* difficult to unit test, although I am using PHPUnit for this tool.

One of the cool things about PHPUnit is that it will bubble up PHP notices, warnings, and errors into an exception. Using that bit of knowledge I've built a tool to recursively `include()` files from a directory in a try/catch block and log any exceptions.

The problem is, this can quickly become a memory hog and crash if I include hundreds of files. I've considered using this but I'm not sure if this "clears" it from memory:

```
// Include file into buffer
ob_start();

include($file);

// Clear file from buffer
ob_clean();
```

What is the best way to handle something of this nature and manage memory/resources appropriately?

**[EDIT]**

Also, this is an **internal** tool that I am developing to help manage the thousands of files containing *untestable* (in a time constraint sense) legacy procedural code.

What about this as a thought?

```
// Enable garbage collector (in case this helps?)
gc_enable();

// Get procedural php and execute it
$fileData = file_get_contents($file);
eval($fileData);

// Clear variable
$fileData = null;
```

Comment: Well, your output buffer has absolutely nothing to do with your application.  That's just for sending data back to the web server, which is sent to the browser.  You'll need another method, which I suspect is going to come down to sandboxing.  http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php

Comment: You can't "uninclude". You can try unsetting variables, but functions and objects can't be "deleted".

Comment: You could diff `$GLOBALS` from before and after including, and then once you're done with the file, you could unset the diff'd variables.

Comment: You should probably build an autoloader for including files on the basis of a class, instead of including all files? That said, I'm not sure you can unload anything. Maybe run them as separate tests?

Comment: @arxanas, That does nothing to solve the problem.

Comment: @Brad Why doesn't it? Perhaps I misunderstand the problem.

Comment: @arxanas, Clearing `$GLOBALS` isn't going to unload any classes that have been loaded... it will only clear things in `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: You need to run the include tests in "batches" in separate scripts. EG, step1, step2... Because otherwise the memory use will increase greatly, as you said.

Comment: @Brad If it's legacy code then perhaps it doesn't contain classes.

Comment: @arxanas, Alright, suppose it's "legacy code" that has the non-real-world predictability of not using classes.  It still doesn't matter, as you aren't stuffing that code in `$GLOBALS`.  Do a test to see for yourself.

Comment: @Brad, none of these files contain classes...straight procedural garbage. LOL.

Comment: Take the advice of @Nanne if possible, break your tests down into batches.

Comment: @Brad See my edit with another thought I have as a solution?

Comment: @cillosis I believe that `file_get_contents()`/`eval()` is pretty much what `include` does underneath. My instinct tells me that the way to do this would be `exec('php '.__FILE__.' /file/being/included')` - start a whole new PHP process with its own memory space, let it process the file and then when its done all the memory will be freed immediately. Although I'm also thinking that wrapping `include` in a function and calling `gc_collect_cycles()` on the last line of it might solve the problem - the only thing left in memory would be class/function definitions from the included files.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you for that valuable input! I'm coming to a similar conclusion in my research/testing. I'm determined to make this work efficiently, LOL.

Comment: @DaveRandom, Does the sandbox not do the same thing, but in a less hackish way?  I haven't tested it, but it seems that freeing the memory once the object referencing the plugin is collected shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Marc-B: Objects can easily be deleted using `unset`. You probably meant "classes" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you create a separate CLI script (the "tester") that will include one file at a time and log the exceptions, and have your main script (the "iterator") iterate through / recurse into the directories of scripts you need to test and invoke the tester script via the shell for each file?

Comment: It's either that or I use PCNTL to run each iteration as a seperate process. Your idea may be easier to impliment though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh, interesting, I wasn't even aware of PCNTL before. It does sound like my suggestion would be easier to implement, so that's appealing if it'll perform adequately and there aren't important or necessary advantages provided by PCNTL for your problem. You're welcome.