# Exception Bubbling with passthru(), system(), or exec()

Tags: php, exception, exec, try-catch

In my own tests, I have been unable to bubble exceptions using system-like commands. Just curious if there is a way to make this occur?

**test1.php:**

```
<?php

   try {

      // None of these (which throw an exception)
      // allow exception to be caught here
      passthru("php -f test2.php");
      system("php -f test2.php");
      exec("php -f test2.php");

   } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo( "Caught exception: " . $e->getMessage() );
   }
?>
```

**test2.php:**

```
<?php

   // Throw an exception
   throw new Exception();       

?>
```

I know it can be caught with an include, but for [my purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797471/php-uninclude-or-remove-from-memory), I can't use that. Is there a way to catch or "bubble up" exceptions when executing a script this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @minitech said, you would have to listen on `STDERR`.

When you call a PHP script via the `system()` access commands, it runs them as a separate process, which your calling script downs not have access to.

If you want to do it this way, you might be able to look into the [`POSIX`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.posix.php) extension.

If not, you will have to test the response from the `system()` call, rather than trying to catch the `Exception`

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look into this. I feel like I should be able to execute a script in it's own memory scope and catch any exceptions, followed by a end of execution/memory cleanup prior to any other processing. Something tells me I am making this more complicated than it really is.

Comment: Remember the context. When you run `shell_exec`, `system()`, etc.. it drops out of the PHP context when you issue a command. Why not just `include`/`require` and execute from you script, rather than making a system call?

Comment: Because I am iterating through files for a [testing tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797471/php-uninclude-or-remove-from-memory) I'm creating and it could potentially involve including 100's if not 1000's of files which would eat up memory until it crashed. Looking for alternative solution to execute a script and catch it's exceptions, then clear it from memory.

Comment: But how to listen on STDERR?

Answer (score 1):

No, the best you can do is read STDERR. `php` can only output text.